# Using a label in a having clause in sqlachemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a label in a having clause with sqlalchemy, but I'm having problems getting it working. I'm trying something like this:

```
qry = db.session.query(
         Foo.id,
         Foo.name,
         (Foo.max_stuff - func.sum(Bar.stuff)).label('rstuff')
).join(Bar) \
 .group_by(Foo.id) \
 .having('rstuff' >= "some_data_passed_in_by_customer")

for res in qry.all(): 
    print res
```

But get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: having() argument must be of type sqlalchemy.sql.ClauseElement or string
```

If I try changing the having statement to:

```
.having('rstuff >= "some_data_passed_in_by_customer"')
```

Then it seems to work alright, but I'm guess that would lead to a sql injection vulnerability. I could do this via raw sql, but I would like to avoid that if I could. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try any of the two versions below (not sure the second one works on MySQL though):

```
rstuff = (Foo.max_stuff - db.func.sum(Bar.stuff))
qry = (
    db.session.query(
        Foo.id,
        Foo.name,
        rstuff.label('rstuff')
    )
    .join(Bar)
    .group_by(Foo.id)

    # version-1: probably universal, but repeats the expression
    .having(rstuff >= 3)
    # version-2: might depend on the RMDBS engine
    # .having(db.literal_column('rstuff') >= 3)
)
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. The first solution gave me an operational errror like "Unkown column Bar.stuff in having clause". Tried to do a join in the rstuff variable up top, but that gave me another error "AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'join".

For the second one, it compiled and printed out the query, but it seemed to ignore the >= portion of it. That part of the qry.statement was "HAVING :param_1", and it returned all of the results of the tables, instead of only the ones where rstuff was >= 3

Comment: This is mysql fwiw. I ended up getting by this by just querying everything in the table, then doing some if statements on the results to check if rstuff >= 3. This is a very small data set, so it works fine for me, but it would still be nice to figure out how to properly do this.

Comment: EDIT: On the second example, I was doing a dumb and had it as '.having(db.literal('rstuff' >= 3)). Fixed that, now I am seeing a different error: "Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'rstuff'".

Comment: I am sorry I cannot be more *mysql* specific. One thing some DBs require is that all the columns in the result set are present in the `group_by`. In case of your query this means that the `group_by` should be `.group_by(Foo.id).group_by(Foo.name)` because both `id` and `name` are in the result columns. BTW, can you print out and share the SQL statement which gets generated?