# SQLAlchemy reference label in Having clause

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

We have a query that we need to use as part of a select, and also in the having clause. The problem is that the resulting SQL expands the query in both places when I would expect to not expand it in the having clause.

Its a complex query with lots of models that I cannot show here, but the idea is simple.

```
Query(Model.name, subQuery.label('total')) \
    .filter(Model.country == some_country) \
    -group_by(Model.skill) \
    -having(subQuery > some_total)
```

We can actually make the query work without expanding the subquery with raw SQL, but we cannot seem to find a way of reproducing that with the orm.

We expect the sql for the having clause to look like

```
HAVING total > some_total
```

but we get the whole select from subQuery again in the having clause.

I've tried

```
having(subQuery.subquery() > some_total)
having(subQuery.as_scalar() > some_total)
```

Performance difference between the raw SQL and the orm like query are huge in our case, so it's not really an option to have the subQuery executed on both places.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313872/using-a-label-in-a-having-clause-in-sqlachemy/30320526#30320526? Note that referencing a column alias in HAVING [is a MySQL extension](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases), and I'm fairly certain that any optimizer worth its salt would not actually perform the subquery twice, even if the original query looks that way.

Comment: Well, was wrong on the optimization part. Apparently (at least some) DBMS designers think that in general it'd cost too much in the query planning phase, in comparison to the returns in query performance.

Comment: yeah, so far we were not able to figure it out. I'm wondering if there's a way of doing it with expression language or the end result would be the same. If not I guess the only option would be to do it with a raw SQL because the performance difference is huge in our case.

Comment: Check the linked Q/A. You can use for example `literal_column()` to create a literal alias reference in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a label in a having clause in sqlachemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313872/using-a-label-in-a-having-clause-in-sqlachemy)

Comment: @IljaEverilä yep, that worked, than you!  there's always something else to try with sqlalchemy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like referencing the label with `literal_column` solves the issue. Bear in mind that this will only work with MySQL

```
Query(Model.name, subQuery.label('total')) \
    .filter(Model.country == some_country) \
    -group_by(Model.skill) \
    -having(literal_column('total') > some_total)
```