# How to covert SQL CASE expression to SQL Alchemy with an alias

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to covert given SQL Case expression with an alias to SQL Alchemy ORM

```sql
SELECT `id` AS `emailId`, `email`, `type`,
CASE WHEN `type` = 'Home' THEN 1
WHEN `type` = 'Work' THEN 2
ELSE 4 END `s_order`
FROM `emails`
WHERE `id` = '1121212'
ORDER BY `s_order` ASC'
```

I know case can be used like this

```
from sqlalchemy import case

stmt = select([users_table]).\
            where(
                case(
                    [
                        (users_table.c.name == 'wendy', 'W'),
                        (users_table.c.name == 'jack', 'J')
                    ],
                    else_='E'
                )
            )
```

but how do I include `s_order` ??

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select as in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576382/select-as-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't think so, please look again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a label in a having clause in sqlachemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313872/using-a-label-in-a-having-clause-in-sqlachemy)

Comment: Also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555920/python-sqlalchemy-label-usage